# "I need" vs. "one needs", should "need" be plural and why?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Given the sentence:

> These are the basic security features **I need** in order to operate safely.

And the sentence

> These are the basic security features **one needs** in order to operate safely.

I am 99% sure that `need` should be plural in `one needs`. If so why would it be plural (we are using the word `one`)?

It would not make sense to say

> These are the basic security features **one need** in order to operate safely.

I have heard it used in singular:

> One need not worry.

Why does it work in singular there but not elsewhere?

Comment: "One" is a 3rd person singular pronoun.  "Needs" is not the plural of "need" but the 3rd person singular of "need".

Comment: i.e., 'needs' is marked to agree with a 3rd person singular subject; and 'one' is a determiner whose noun may be reduced, and it MAY imply an unknown gender: 'If one needs a book, he may find one at the library.'